# Passing enum type as argument in Dart 2

Tags: enums, dart

Just like passing class type as argument to method I want to pass enum, as I  want to write a general method which operates on enum.

I tried:

```
  void foo(E):
    print(E.values[0])
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way?

Comment: "Just like passing class type". I guess you mean "class' instance" because in Dart you can't call static methods on passed class types either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might work for you

```
typedef EnumValues<T> = List<T> Function();

void main() {
  foo<E1>(() => E1.values);
  foo<E2>(() => E2.values);
}

enum E1 { a, b }
enum E2 { c, d }

void foo<T>(EnumValues<T> valuesFn) {
  var values = valuesFn();
  for (var v in values) {
    print(v);
  }
}
```

See comments - shorter version

```
void main() {
  foo<E1>(E1.values);
  foo<E2>(E2.values);
}

enum E1 { a, b }
enum E2 { c, d }

void foo<T>(List<T> values) {
  for (var v in values) {
    print(v);
  }
  print(values[0]);
}
```

Comment: I also want index of the value inside foo. Can I somehow get it? if you could edit and add that too.

Comment: `var values = ...` is set to an array of values. You can just use `values[0]` after this line.

Comment: You could just pass the list directly instead of a function returning the list. The `EnumType.values` list is constant, so you won't cause any extra overhead that way, like you do when creating the closure.

Comment: Thanks, was just thinking too complicated :-/