# Use Enum.values in with generic class in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, enums

This question was asked nine years ago for javascript but I couldn't find the answer for the dart. I try to achieve json serialization with enum. There are some solutions with libraries but I want to answer dart logic.

```
enum GenderType{
  Male,
  Female,
  NonBinary
}
```

```
T? getEnum<T>(String key) {
     return (T as Enum).values[_pref?.getInt(key)];
}
```

I want to write like this. Although I can call GenderType.values, I cannot call them as T.values.

Comment: This may be the answer you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52154155/2533109

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. First of all `Enum` class doesn't contain `values` list. The second reason is `values` in enum is a static field and you can't call static methods or fields on the generic type even you cast them to the specific one.

You have to change your function like this:

```
T? getEnum<T>(List<T> values, String key) {
  //needs some additional checks if _pref is null or getInt(key) returned null
  return values[_pref?.getInt(key)];
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
GenderType? result = getEnum(GenderType.values, "some_key");
```

If you want to create `T? getEnum<T>(String key)` you can achieve this but in a **bad way**. So it is just an example:

```dart
T? getEnum<T>(String key) {
  if(T == GenderType) {
    //needs some additional checks if _pref is null or getInt(key) returned null
    return GenderType.values[_pref?.getInt(key)] as T;
  }

  //if(T == anotherType) {}
  //and so on

  throw Exception("Unhandled type: $T");
}
```

But much better to use a separate method for each type.

Comment: It's not generic type. I don't want to use GenderType in getEnum function. Because there are lots of different enum class like GenderType and this isn't reusable like this code block

Comment: @UmutADALI Yes, because we can't create this function generic from your example. I edited my answer and changed the function signature to achieve the expected result. But with the original function signature, I believe we can't do this.